# Using java, how to change the default operator of match query to AND in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When using java api as below

```
query.must(matchQuery("name", object.getName()));
```

The resulted elastic query is

```
"bool":{
    "must":[
      {"match":{"name":{"query":"De Michael Schuster","operator":"OR","boost":1.0}}}
.....
```

Right now I am getting back document with name : De OR Michael OR Schuster as expected.
I want to change the operator to AND to match the whole string.

I know I can use term query, but that is not an option in my scenario.

I came across this, but the answer is not given - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/changing-the-default-operator-for-search-api/47033

How can I achieve this using Java ?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `AND` operator? It will match anything containing De *and* Michael *and* Schuster, regardless of order and other tokens. "De Michael Schuster" will match, but so will "Schuster Michael De" and "John Schuster Williams De Gabriel Michael".

If you want to search for the phrase "De Michael Schuster", i.e. with the words in exactly that order and no other words intermingled, you might want to use `match_phrase` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
query.must(matchQuery("name", object.getName()).operator(Operator.AND));
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. But it returns no result when serached against some string with '.'. Fr eg. I have documents with name as : "Dr. med. Elisabeth Bauer". When I use the above query with AND operator, it does not return anything ( Using OR returns more than one document, which is expected). But when the string does not contain '.', it works perfectly with AND operator. For eg., for string " Stefan Drumm", it returns the document. Any idea why this is happening? Of course your answer is correct and accepted, but I am lost here. Let me know if you want me to post a new question.

Comment: FYI, a new question was posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63901824/108326.